# How do you enable rendering of attributes in Cycle.js/dom?

Tags: dom, cyclejs

I have the following snippet:

```
      button('.textbutton', {
          type: "button",
          onclick: `toggleVisibility('#abs-${submission.submission_id}');`
        },
        'Abstract'
      ),
      a( {href: "https://localhost:8080"}, 'View Article'),
      div(`#abs-${submission.submission_id}`,
        {style: 'display:none'}, submission.abstract
      ),
```

This seems to render as just:

```
<button class="textbutton">Abstract</button>
<a>View Article</a>
<div id="abs-1405603">Text not shown on SO...</div>
```

Note that none of the attributes are being rendered. My cycle.js imports in this file are simply:

```
import {VNode, div, a, button, h3, img, hr, b, p, span} from "@cycle/dom";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [snabbdom](https://github.com/snabbdom/snabbdom).

It should be

```
a({
  attrs: {
    href: '#'
  }
}, ['link'])
```

And events go under `on`, like

```
button('.textbutton', {
  attrs: {
    type: 'button'
  },
  on: {
    click: () => {} // here goes function
  },
}, ['Abstract'])
```

You have to create object with key `attrs` and then attributes.

The only case when something like this will work are [modules](https://github.com/snabbdom/snabbdom#modules-documentation) `class` and `style`. `class` takes CSS class as key and condition as value, e.g.

```
div({
  class: {
    'block': true,
    'hidden': isVisible === false
  }
}, [/**/])
```

When condition is falsy then class will not be present.

`style` is just like CSS styles key - value:

```
div({
  style: {
    'display': 'none'
  }
}, [/**/])
```

Also with Cycle you should not attach events directly to DOM by yourself but call source driver DOM to do that, e.g. `sources.DOM.select('a').events('click')` and then you have clicks stream.